# In my django project, the DB column order doesn't match the model field declaration order -- could this be an issue?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a django project where (for various reasons, the main one being I didn't use south from the get-go, and I migrated data using mysqldump) my DB tables in some cases have different column ordering than the corresponding django model field declaration order.   Other than not being able to conveniently copy data between instances of the project (say, production to staging, and this is a big pain, yes), is there some risk that the project itself when running will misbehave in unpredictable ways due to this model field/DB column difference?   Is this situation a red flag and should I be set to reorder my DB table column ordering to fix this immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be a problem.

Django does not care if a database table contains columns that are not defined in the model, which also implies that it does not care about the order of the columns in that table. Essentially, it only cares about whether it can find the data defined in your model somewhere in the table, and ignores any additional information that may exist in the db.

For a little more on Django/Database Schema interaction, you can reference the Django Book section on this: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html

Comment: This is mostly true, although obviously additional not-null columns without a db-level default that Django doesn't know about will cause problems on insert.